# What is the correct verb to use for somebody who says nonsense just to make a person smile?

Tags: word-request, verbs

What verb should I use when somebody is saying nonsense with the purpose of making a person smile?

I was thinking of *tease*, but the OALD says it means, "to laugh at somebody and make jokes about them, either in a friendly way or in order to annoy or embarrass them." In my case, I am not talking of laughing at somebody or making jokes about them. I could say nonsense about something I have (presumably) done, or about something that (presumably) happened.

Comment: Maybe act/play the goat? One of its definitions.

Comment: Buffoonery might work?

Comment: *playing the fool?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call this ***being silly***.  If my friends or I are being silly, we're usually trying to get a smile out of one another.

Answer (score 5):

The words suggested in comments (*[play the fool](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play_the_fool)*,“To behave in a foolish or comical manner”, and noun  *[buffoonery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buffoonery)*, “foolishness, silliness; the behaviour expected of a buffoon”) are good; also consider   *[josh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/josh#Verb)*, “To tease someone in a kindly fashion”, and *[prattle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prattle#Verb)*,  “To speak incessantly and in a childish manner; to [babble](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/babble#Verb)”.  Also see *[prate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prate#Verb)*, near-synonyms of which include  *blabber, chatter, clack, gabble, gibber, maunder, palaver, piffle, prattle, twaddle*.

Comment: Isn't _buffoon_ used as pejorative?

Comment: Yes, in senses like  “An unintentionally ridiculous person”  *[buffoon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buffoon#Noun)* is pejorative, but it also has a not-pejorative sense  “One who acts in a silly or ridiculous fashion; a clown or fool”.

Comment: Buffoon is a pejorative that means something different give the context and tone of voice. If it is mild it indicates that you're just joking around. If it is severe it means you hold the buffoon in contempt.

Comment: @Xenson I see. In Italian, _buffone_ ("buffoon") would always be a pejorative, together with _pagliaccio_ ("clown"). Of course, _pagliaccio_ is not a pejorative when you are really working as clown in a circus, and you are saying what your work is.

Answer (score 0):

If the "person" is a baby, one expression is "to talk baby talk." That is to speak a collection of meaningless, but good sounding syllables, because babies can't understand words anyway. But they can "smile" to pleasant sounds.